# jQuery focus() on textbox on button click ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, focus

I am developing an application on the iPad using jQuery and HTML5.

I want to give focus to a `textbox` on a button click. The button functionality is to clear the `textbox` value. After clearing the value, I want the focus to be there in the `textbox`.

My code is:

```
function onclickclearbtn(){
    $('#txtbox').val('');
    $('#txtbox').focus();
}
```

i am using jquery 1.4.4

Comment: It's not clear what the question here is.

Comment: i just want to retain the focus on a textbox on button click.

Comment: I gathered that from your original post, but you've included some code here without asking a question. Is it working? Are you running into some specific issues? You haven't included your markup so it's impossible to comment on the code you've shown so far.

Comment: You would need to use an event handler on the button element to determine when it's clicked, in which case your `onclickclearbtn()` callback will be called. Note, on the iPad I'm not sure which event handler (click? tap? I don't know) specifically would be best for this, either.

Comment: above code is not working in ipad.The actual scenario is that i have a pop-up with textbox and two buttons.once the pop-up comes and i touch on the textbox keyboard appears but when i m touching the clear button ,it is clearing the textbox but the keyboard disappears

Comment: the click is firing in ipad as well.

Comment: You've provided such a small piece of your code, it's impossible (IMO) to determine what your problem is. Post enough of your code to explain the entire problem, and post a http://jsfiddle.net demo if possible.

Comment: I just want to bring the keyboard of ipad on button click .onclick of button i am calling above function which is just clearing the textbox content,but keyboard is disappearing .So i want to make the keyboard to come on button click that's why i have used focus event but it's not helping me

Comment: Guys am i clear?Please help me out on this

Comment: @kinkutta i m just using a simple <input type="text" onclick="onclickclearbtn()"/>

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something like overlaying the button inside the textfield. Such as http://cor.to/focustest (http://fiddle.jshell.net/tomasdev/W8udu/show/light/)

Why? iOS doesn't provide a way to `.focus()` since it may be annoying for the user to have constantly the keyboard popped up. So it requires a real user action to the input to show the keyboard.

What we do? Just put a transparent input over the button :)